# Symbolic matrix multiplication on GPU using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a matrix `M` with approximately 300 rows and columns. Each entry contains a symbolic expression, and there are around 40 symbols in total. Doing something like `M*M` can take a long time (hours). Is there a way to do this symbolic matrix multiplication on a gpu using sympy, or more generally in python?

Comment: What do you mean by symbolic expression ? An example of input/code snippet would be useful here. Nevertheless, using [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) library can be quite starightfoward for linear algebra operations on GPU

Comment: I doubt it.  Unless you can find something in the `sympy` documentation about `gpu`.  With symbols in the matrix the kind of image/numeric calculations that a GPU handles are irrelevant.

Comment: Sympy doesn't use the GPU but the Matrix class is slow. There is a new mostly internal matrix class that might work but it depends what kinds of expressions you have (e.g. are they polynomials with rational coefficients?). The performance also depends on whether it is sparse. Also you might prefer to use symengine.

Comment: The entries of the matrix are indeed polynomials with rational coefficients, but the matrix is not very sparse. Is the matrix class you're referring to part of sympy?

Answer (score 3):

**You're in luck!** I just levelled up on this a few minutes ago. The optimal solution for parallelizing SymPy expressions on [G|T]PU hardware is (as of mid-2021) [Aesara](https://aesara.readthedocs.io), a well-maintained fork of [the now-defunct Theano package foolishly discontinued in the mistaken belief that Tensorflow was better](https://github.com/Theano/Theano). <sup>*Spoiler alert: it wasn't.*</sup>

Since the OP sadly failed to supply a minimal length example (MLE) for us to mutilate, we'll just copypasta a mostly useless example demonstrating the core API concepts:

```
# SymPy -> Aesara translater, bundled with SymPy.
from sympy.printing.aesaracode import aesara_function

# Arbitrary SymPy expression.
from sympy import sin
from sympy.abc import x
expr = sin(x)/x

# GPU-parallelized Aesara function compiled from that expression! Yup.
f = aesara_function([x], [expr])
```

Generally speaking, the optimal solution is [whatever SymPy's "Numeric Computation" documentation says it is](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html). Currently, that means [Aesara](https://aesara.readthedocs.io); since data science in Python changes faster than a King Cobra biting the village hand that feeds it, everything has probably already changed by the time *you* read this. Since [the aforementioned documentation is surprisingly intelligible](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html), go there first instead. That's your optimum landing page for all things optimizing SymPy.

Comment: "the now-defunct Theano package foolishly discontinued in the mistaken belief that Tensorflow was better"

Could you please tell me more about this? I was a Theano user back in 2017 year. I tried to use TF (and found it very user non-friendly) but then switched to pytorch.